# mysql.server start not working on mac

Tags: mysql, unix, mysql-workbench, bash

I have installed mysql and I get the version of mysql from command prompt by

```
mysql --version.
```

But when I try to start / stop my server from command prompt by

```
 mysql.server start
```

I get an error

```
-bash: mysql.server: command not found
```

Have edited my .bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Where is mysql.server located? Maybe, not inside `/usr/local/mysql/bin/`?

Comment: when I do which mysql I get  /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql @user4035

Comment: Yeah. But you run a command `mysql.server` and not `mysql`.

Comment: Are you saying to run 'mysql.server start' or ' which mysql.server'

Comment: What about `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe`?

Comment: Posted it as an answer, so the question could be closed

Answer (score 0):

Use this command: `sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe&`